# How to digitally sign a XML File in ASP.NET using USB token and capicom tool?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, digital-signature, capicom

I want to know how to digitally sign a XML file in ASP.NET C# using USB token?

I want to know **how to get certificates from the mosearbear USB token and using the private key contained in it digitally sign a XML file**?

As the **USB is on client machine and i want to sign the XMl file on client system** so how to do that?

What i know is that it is **not easy to access a device on client machine** but ***i have come to know that it can be done with capicom but don't know how***.

What i have come to know recently is that microsoft discontinued capicom. So what's its alternative?

I have got a peice of code but that doesn't seems to what i am looking for. Can anyone help me out?

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509CertificateCollection certificates =  X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(store.Certificates,
                                                                                        "Certificados conocidos",
                                                                                        "Por favor seleccione el certificado con el cual desea firmar",
                                                                                        X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection
                                                                                        );
        store.Close();
        X509Certificate2 certificate = null;
        if (certificates.Count != 0)
        {
            //The selected certificate
            certificate = (X509Certificate2)certificates[0];
        }
        else
        {
            //The user didn't select a certificate
            //return "El usuario canceló la selección de un certificado";
        }
        //Check certificate's atributes to identify the type of certificate (censored)
        if (certificate.Issuer != "CN=............................., OU=................., O=..., C=US")
        {
            //The selected certificate is not of the needed type
           // return "El certificado seleccionado no corresponde a un token ...";
        }
        //Check if the certificate is issued to the current user
        //if (!certificate.Subject.ToUpper().Contains(("E=" + pUserADLogin + "@censoreddomain.com").ToUpper()))
        //{
        //    //return "El certificado seleccionado no corresponde al usuario actual";
        //}
        //Check if the token is currently plugged in
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        //XmlElement element = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Content", SignedXml.XmlDsigNamespaceUrl.ToString());
        //element.InnerText = "comodin";
       // xmlDoc.AppendChild(element);
        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml();
        //try
        //{
        //    signedXml.SigningKey = certificate.PrivateKey;
        //}
        //catch
        //{
        //    //USB Token is not plugged in
        //   // return "El token no se encuentra conectado al equipo";
        //}
        //DataObject dataObject = new DataObject();
        //dataObject.Data = xmlDoc.ChildNodes;
        //dataObject.Id = "CONTENT";
        //signedXml.AddObject(dataObject);
        //Reference reference = new Reference();
        //reference.Uri = "#CONTENT";
        //signedXml.AddReference(reference);
        //Attempt to sign the data. The user will be prompted to enter his PIN
        try
        {
           // signedXml.ComputeSignature();
        }
        catch
        {
            //User didn't enter the correct PIN
           // return "Hubo un error confirmando la identidad del usuario";
        }
        // The user has signed with the correct token
```

Comment: As far as I know there is no changes in security since duplicate question was asked - you still need trusted client side component.

Comment: I'm afraid current version of you post does not look like you asking about capicom. Please edit your question to make it clear why it is not duplicate of "how to sign XML in ASP.Net with C# code".